# How do I do the equivalent of "#define SomeValue 5" in transact sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, macros

I have to make a long transact sql script where I will have to use the same value
many times, and I don't want to write the literal value each time, but use what in C would be a preprocessor macro.

The point is that I will be running this script many times, with different values for "SomeValue" and I only want to have the literal value one place in the script, at the top where I can see it and change it as needed, and then run the script again.

Comment: `DECLARE @SomeValue INT = 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't define a constant in SQL, you can make a variable:

```
DECLARE @SomeValue INT = 5

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = @SomeValue

SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable
WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeValue + 5
```

There are limitations on where you can use variables though. For example, you cannot use them in [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements. If you do, you will get an error:

```
DECLARE @SomeValue INT = 5
CREATE TABLE TestTable(IntColumn INT DEFAULT(@SomeValue))
```

Will give this error:

> Variables are not allowed in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: What happens when I use it in a default constraint:
`constraint df_blabla default @SomeValue`

does that constraint then somehow (later, at runtime) depend on the value of SomeValue, or is the constraint absolutely equal to on defined with a literal 5 ?

Comment: It isn't possible to use variables in constraints, or in any DDL for that matter.

Comment: then what does one do ?

Comment: Not much you can do, you can't use variables so you have to use literals.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring the value with the default at the very beginning of the script, like:            DECLARE @SomeValue int = 5